# Bootstrap how to foreach with columns inside

Tags: php, css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

I have a foreach and I want to place 4 columns then break in a new row and start again but for some reason i got the column number 5(test2) bad pushed like this picture:

[image: problem]

should be like this:

[image: solution]

here is the code to generate that:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  Secciones
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                   <div class="row">
                      @foreach ($boards as $board)
                          <div class="col-md-3">
                              <h3>{{$board->boaName}}</h3>
                              @foreach ($subboards as $subboard)
                                  @if($subboard->boaId == $board->id)
                                    <ul>
                                        <li><a href="">{{$subboard->subboaName}}</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                  @endif
                              @endforeach
                          </div>
                      @endforeach
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!--End container-->
```

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `foreach` loop outside of the `<div class="row">`? If that doesn't work do you think you could mock this up in a jsFiddle example?

Answer (score 0):

You need a test after 4 iterations to close and open again the row div.

Comment: i know but bootstrap should push cols, the grid system explains that, it does that but incorrectly, i want to do this that way without any variables or counters

Answer (score 0):

If you know how many columns to expect, you could do the following (I've ommited your inner content of each column for my example - I've also left the counter in so you can see the incrementation for testing):

```
$i = 1;
foreach($boards as $board) {
    if($i == 1 || $i == 5 || $i == 9) {
        echo "<div class='row'>";
        echo "<div class='col-md-3'>" . $i++ . "</div>";
    }
    elseif($i%4 == 0) {
        echo "<div class='col-md-3'>" . $i++ . "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    } else {
        echo "<div class='col-md-3'>" . $i++ . "</div>";
    }
}
```

What's happening here is if the column count is the 4th iteration, it should echo out an opening `<div class="row">` as well as a column. If the current column is divisible by 4, it should echo out a column with an extra closing `</div>` (to close the `row` class.)

If the current count is neither of the above, it simply echo's out a column.

You can, of course, mod the above if the amount of potential columns is unknown.

Comment: I know i can do that but I just wanted to know why bootstrap ain't working for me, he should push back the cols :S.

Comment: @Sociopath Oh sorry, thought you wanted a solution too. I see this happen with my projects too, the column that should simply go to the next line seems to align itself tight to the bottom of the immediate one above. I think this has to do with the way the row aligns children columns. I'm not sure of the exact reasons I'm afraid :-(... You could also `clear: left` the 5th column